# Accessing a DOM attached function in an iframe from the parent window

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, iframe

Here is my problem:

1. an iframe is opened in a parent window;
2. a function loaded in the iframe (js file) is used to modify a DOM located in the iframe;

The function is working perfectly when used in the iframe:

$(DOMId).function();

I am trying hard to do the same from the parent window but without success...
I always get xxx.'function' is not a function.

I tried to access directly functions and variables from the loaded script without problem. For instance:
jQuery(iframeId)[0].contentWindow.direcfunction();

But I can not find the way to call a function attached to a DOM in the iframe.
I tried many things, the latest being:

var iframeDOM = document.getElementById(iframeId).contentDocument.getElementById(DOMId);
jQuery(iframeDOM).function();

Has anybody a solution to this?

Comment: You can't access the iframe if you're on a different domain due to security issues.

Comment: try: `document.getElementById(iframeId).contentDocument.$("#"+DOMId).function()`

Comment: Same domain, there is no cross domain content.

Comment: A. Wolff: returns 'document.getElementById(iframeId).contentDocument.$' is not a function.

Comment: Sorry it is: `document.getElementById(iframeId).contentWindow.$("#"+DOMId).function()` and call it only once iframe is loaded, so could be set in iframe onload event or even window onload event depending use case

Comment: The iframe is already fully loaded, is onload necessary? It says now undefined (IE) or blank (FF). But the function is not launched.

Comment: Before calling this method, the method has been to be included. I'd be really really easier to fix your issue if only you posted any online sample which replicate your issue.

Comment: I will put an example online shortly.

Comment: I made it work with document.getElementById("iframe").contentWindow.jQuery("#picker").colpick({...}) in the example I was trying to build. There must be something wrong in my original code. I will check it again.

Comment: I finally solved. The query from A. Wolff is the correct. There was a last problem due to the way colpick works that prevented me to make it work immediately. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved it. The query from A. Wolff is the correct one:

```
document.getElementById("iframe").contentWindow.jQuery("#picker").colpick({...})
```

There was a last problem due to the way colpick works. It prevented me to make it work immediately.

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure with JQuery (although should be easy), but what happens if you try the following plain javascript ?

```
document.getElementById('yourIFrameID').contentWindow.yourFunctionInsideYourIFrame();
```

Comment: I can access a function directly from the iframe without a problem. To be exact, I am using the colpick extension. To initialize it in the iframe, I use $(DomId).colpick({...}) in the iframe. I can not find the way to initialize it in the iFrame from the parent window. I tried many syntaxes to get the DOM in the iframe. But each time I try to apply .colpick({...}) to the new DOM syntax, it returns 'colpick is not a function'...

Comment: Try to call what I wrote from your parent window. If colpick() is declared in the IFrame, you should be able to call it with something like this from the parent : document.getElementById('yourIFrameID').contentWindow.colpick();

Comment: What colpick.js looks like: 
(function ($) {
 var colpick = function () {...}
 }();
 $.fn.extend({
  colpick: colpick.init,
 });
})(jQuery);

Comment: How about this : $('#yourIFrameID').contents().find("#yourDOMElementID").colpick({...});

Comment: Are you immediately trying to call your function or did you also tried to wrap all this inside something like : $('#iframeID').load(function(){...}

Comment: I never used load as the iframe is already fully loaded when I use the colpick function... Is there another utility for the load function?